# How do I replace a certain combination of characters / inputs?

Tags: java, eclipse, carriage-return, replaceall, linefeed

I want to replace a `"` followed by `\n\r (enter)` with just `"`

I've tried multiple variations on:

```
receivedData = receivedData.replaceAll(\\" + [\n\r], \\", );
```

How does one replace a combination of characters and symbols / carriage return / line feed?

EDIT:
Still not solved using current suggestion , I still get the following lines back which I want to be on one line:

```
+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","+31626187086",,"16/11/25,09:33:58+04"
Test
```

Comment: `replaceAll("\"\n\r", "\"")`. You sure about `\n\r`? On Windows, it's normally `\r\n`.

Comment: You're better off using `System.lineSeparator()` instead of literals. Also please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I got \n\r from replace my empty lines code, might be r n instead, thank you for your answers

Comment: I will try to get this going but my code is not runnable without libraries and might be a bit of a hassle to provide a relevant example. I am using the code to recieve serial data streams and parse them into a text file for processing in excel.

Comment: What usually happens is when you try to extract a MCVE, you figure out yourself where the problem is.

Comment: I am working on one but whilst doing so running into declaration issues that are not relevant to this question (declaring the serial input).

Comment: System.lineSeparator() has saved me, I didn't use it like I should've, how can I mark this question as solved?

Comment: You can't mark a question as solved, you can only *accept answers* which marks the question as solved. I've added my comment as an answer, so you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Why is this tagged Eclipse? Does not look like it's about Eclipse's search and replace dialog, so only Java-related, not IDE-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using literals for new line characters is dangerous, since it's platform dependent or may contain a typo (wrong order of `\n\r` chars). I'd recommend using [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) method instead.

So your code in this case may look like:

```
receivedData = receivedData.replaceAll("\"" + System.lineSeparator(), "\"");
```